# ES6 Classes with GSAP says can't Tween null object

Tags: ecmascript-6, gsap, es6-class

My code is as below. Any ideas how can I call this.rule ? I am trying to use GSAP's TweenMax with a plugin called CSSRulePlugin to animate the pseudo elements.

```
class animate {
  constructor() {
    this.rule = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(".menu a:before");
    this.target = document.querySelectorAll(".menu a");
  }

  init() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.target.length; i++) { 
      this.handleClick(i);
    }
  }

  handleClick(index) {
    this.target[index].addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      TweenMax.to(this.rule, 0.2, {cssrule:{x: '+10px'}});
    });
  }

}

let Animate = new animate();
Animate.init();
```

Keeps saying `can not Tween null object`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may have `this.target.length` elements, but you don't have that number of rules. By the way, what is the purpose of the `self` variable?

Comment: I used self because when I tried something using this.trigger[index] the code doesn't work.

Comment: How does `TweenMax.to` know which element to apply to? Looks like `self.rule[index]` should be `self.target[index]`, or better: `event.currentTarget`.

Comment: `Self.target[index]` is animating the entire link, but I want the pseudo element of the link to animate.

Comment: Pseudo elements don't exist in the DOM and therefore cannot be selected. Did you read somewhere that this is possible?

Comment: Pseudo elements can be animated using the CSSRulePlugin in GSAP. - https://greensock.com/CSSRulePlugin

Comment: The title doesn't reflect the problem. The class doesn't say 'not defined'. It is TweenMax that says 'cannot Tween null object'. There's no problem with ES6 class itself, it is narrowed down to GSAP stuff.

Comment: Title edited for clarity. I really want to know how to include `this.rule` into TweeMax. My code is all correct but why does it say null object I don't know.

Comment: Did you inspect the value of `this.rule`? Is it what you expect?

Comment: @TheEarlyMan possible for you to create a small fiddle or something please?

Answer (score 1):

[`CSSRulePlugin.getRule` doesn't seem to return an `Array`](https://greensock.com/CSSRulePlugin)

```
var rule = CSSRulePlugin.getRule(".box:after"); 
TweenLite.to(rule, 1, {cssRule:{backgroundColor:"#600", color:"white"}});
```

So, you probably need to change your code:

```js
handleClick(index) {
    this
      .target[index]
      .addEventListener('mouseenter', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let self = this;

        TweenMax.to(self.rule, 0.2, {
          cssrule:{x: '+10px'}
        });
    });
}
```

ps: you don't need `var self = this` because `arrow function inherit the this`.

Comment: if I try `this.rule` (after dropping self) or `self.rule` with `self = this`, either way it just says can not tween null object.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use add remove classes? you can build your animation in css and just add or remove a class at the right moment...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, that's an easy way out, but I want all my animations to be triggered with JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by triggering with JavaScript. If it was me I would create a class for example .animate-to-right and add all the stuff I want to do with my element plus giving it a proper transition or even a delay if necessary and for example on click of a link just add that class to my element

Comment: Yes, I want to do all that, with only JS, an example: using `el.style.opacity=0` instead of `opacity: 0`;

Comment: could you make a pen or a fiddle?